# unable to run a net core docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

After refactoring from docker-compose into separate Docker file for each project, I'm Unable to run the container, it simply exits. I'm using both docker and docker-compose since I'll have more projects down the road.

My docker files are as follows.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:

  customer:
    image: customer
    container_name: customer
    build:
      context: ./Customer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

**Customer/Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2

WORKDIR /Customer

EXPOSE 80

COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/ service/

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "service/Customer.dll"]
```

---

Also I had this within docker-compose file before. How do I map `6001` to `80` within `Dockerfile`?

```
ports:
  - 6001:80
```

---

### Attempt 2

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2

WORKDIR /Customer

ENV DATABASE_HOST=database
ENV DATABASE_NAME=db
ENV DATABASE_USER=sa
ENV DATABASE_PASSWORD=Password

EXPOSE 80

COPY . .

CMD dotnet build

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Customer/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/Department.dll"]
```

---

### Attempt 3

copied from main site.

Copied from here https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

> Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK
>   from:   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

Comment: When you run a container with your Dockerfile, is it running? Did you validate that first

Comment: the logs are empty, no activity, and i check docker container ls, nothing

Comment: `eb3444bdc367        customer             "bash"                   9 minutes ago       Exited (0) 9 minutes ago`

Comment: do you agree with how I wrote the docker and docker-compose files? I'm also runnign `consul`, another service and i see a container listed but this .net core fails

Comment: What does the `service/Customer.dll` entrypoint actually do? Is there a `Main` method in there? What is inside it?

Comment: yes, it has a standalone asp.net core service, and it boots up fine on my localhost.

Comment: I would not agree with how you build your docker file. You are copying from your local computers /bin/release folder, instead of copying the source-code and actually building it in an intermediate container - aka build-environment. It's recommended way of doing it.

Comment: error `It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.` ok, i'm updating to build in the container

Comment: @Henkolicious see updated docker file please

Comment: I'll give you sample to work with, one moment.

Comment: I deleted everything, running from scratch, `Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409`

Comment: @AppDeveloper am I helping, or just making it worse?

Comment: I saw this and I got scared honestly, this is not what they are telling on their website, https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/, I had to step out and back to desk again to have another look, why the docker file on the link is so simpler and why it doesn't work my machine, I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a lazy and basic docker file. I added some comments and some helpful build/debug options, e.g: "RUN ls -al" to list the current directory. Just like a linux VM.

```sh
# step 1 - building you app with SDK as base image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build-env # call the environment build
WORKDIR /build # create a work dir

COPY . . # you don't need copy everything to build your app, but this is for simplisity

RUN ls -al # linux command to list dir content

RUN cd /Customer && dotnet publish -o out # actually building the app and publishing to /out dir

RUN cd /Customer && ls -al # navigate to the folder you copied and list dir

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime # step 2, runtime env (slimmed down container)
WORKDIR /app # create workdir
COPY --from=build-env /<YOUR_BULD_PATH>/out ./ # copy from prev container build output

RUN ls -al # list again

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Department.dll", "--urls", "http://*:6001"] # example from .NET Core 2.2 webapi with port 6005, this might not be your case
```

Now to run the docker-compose, just point out the docker file like you have already done. But both docker/docker-compose should work just fine now. Ofcourse you need to tweak the docker file a bit, i dont know your app or folder structure.

And just a tip, if you want to run your docker file as stand alone, dont forget the args when you start it to map ports --> -p 6001:80

Comment: starting fresh this morning, now I realize couple of things after glancing over and over again, you are creating two containers in here, one is build env and the other runtime env, and then you are copying the dll file from build to run env. oh so we couldn't do it one and we need two containers for that?

Comment: Yes, you will end upp with 2 containers, one build container where you create your .dll:s - then copy them over to your slimmed runtime container. This vid goes over it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGz_cbtCiEA - to view the images on you machine, do `docker images` and to clear all the intermediate (build) containers do `docker system prune --force` which will remove all untagged images

Comment: one last thing, where should I specify env variables, what's the practice? in the `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose` file, never worked in production, just playing locally

Comment: I've several other containers specified in this docker compose, or in other words how do I also share environment variables between containers, for instance all of them receive the same database credentials.

Comment: @AppDeveloper Specify the environment variables in your `docker-compose` file. Then if you want to host your containers in lets say kubernetes, you can override these environment variables there.